# Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/launch_background'

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgKWz.png)




@drawable/launch_background

<!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
running.

```
     This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: i am getting this error when i opened this file and i am using flutter

Comment: <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution that We need to add splash image to all the drawable folder such that flutter will automatically decide which size of image it require for different screen

Comment: Heads up!
Your answer is not a complete solution to this question.
When this occurs, you must enter it as a comment.